# Overwrite community model class not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to overwrite Ebizmarts Mandrill model class , but its not working.
This xml is from Ebizmarts Mandrill config file:

```
<models>
    <ebizmarts_mandrill>
        <class>Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>ebizmarts_mandrill_resource</resourceModel>
    </ebizmarts_mandrill>
    <ebizmarts_mandrill_resource>
        <class>Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Resource</class>
    </ebizmarts_mandrill_resource>
    <core>
        <rewrite>
            <email_template>Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template</email_template>
            <email_queue>Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Queue</email_queue>
        </rewrite>
    </core>
</models>
```

And below xml is from my module config file to rewrite `Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template` file:

```
<email>
    <class>Mage_Updatemandrill_Model</class>
</email>

<ebizmarts_mandrill>
    <rewrite>
        <email_template>Mage_Updatemandrill_Model_Email_Template</email_template>
    </rewrite>
</ebizmarts_mandrill>
```

I have added a test file in shell folder to check which model class is being called and it shows my new module class.

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$item = Mage::getModel('ebizmarts_mandrill/email_template');
echo get_class($item);
```

It returns `Mage_Updatemandrill_Model_Email_Template`.

Comment: what do you mean is not working? You got the right result in your test file.

Comment: It returns 'Mage_Updatemandrill_Model_Email_Template' then what you want ?

Comment: Yes it returns right result in test file but still Ebizmarts_Mandrill_Model_Email_Template being called to send emails .

Comment: Why is your namespace Mage_ ? That is odd. Could lead to oddities due to module load order. You should use your own namespace. Norm is it use COMPANY_MODULENAME On the same thought concerning load order, add a depend in you module ensuring load order. Not sure if any of that may help, but load order can cause oddities.

Comment: i tried by different namespace but still having same issue . now test file returns 'Nafees_Updatemandrill_Model_Email_Template'

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  Question is not clear.It is too confuse what user want

Comment: I'm keeping this open. Just because someone uses a 3rd party module as the example doesn't meet a good answer can't be crafted.