# Rewriting magento module not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to overwrite a module cron file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Nafees_Updatemandrill>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Nafees_Updatemandrill>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>

            <ebizmarts_autoresponder>
                <rewrite>
                    <cron>Nafees_Updatemandrill_Model_Cron</cron>
                </rewrite>
            </ebizmarts_autoresponder>

        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

but its not working.

Below is whats in that module config file:

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <ebizmarts_autoresponder>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>0 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>ebizmarts_autoresponder/cron::autoresponder</model>
            </run>
        </ebizmarts_autoresponder>
    </jobs>
</crontab>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need rewrite cron model class.

So you need to change:

```
<ebizmarts_autoresponder>
    <rewrite>
        <cron>nafees_updatemandrill/cron::autoresponder</cron>
    </rewrite>
</ebizmarts_autoresponder>
```

To:

```
<models>
    <ebizmarts_autoresponder>
        <rewrite>
            <cron>YourModuleNameSpace_ModuleName_Model_Cron</cron>
        </rewrite>
    </ebizmarts_autoresponder>
</models>
```

See [how rewrite class:](http://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/)

Comment: thanks but its not working i updated my question

Comment: ohh i forgot to add _Model . thanks for looking into it

Comment: Can you check this question still haven't found solution for that [link] http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/111537/overwrite-community-model-class-not-working